# Change the Date Format in Email template. Without Editing Phtml File

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

How can edit the date format, in email template without editing phtml. ?
i was used "Date : {{var order.getCreatedAt()}}", Output like 
"2016-08-19 09:15:44", I need remove the time in email template only. i used.
{{var order.getCreatedAt()|formatDateTime:F j, Y}} is not working. please tell me how can show "2016-08-19" on email template please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just fallback order.php, 
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php, in that add a new function

```
Public function getCreatedAtOnlyDate(){
 return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, false);
}
```

In Email Template, {{var order.getCreatedAtOnlyDate('short')}}

It will work I guess.

Comment: I want get the answer without tough php file or phtml file.

Comment: I will try to check it